# Como puedo crear y rellenar una matriz MxN

Tags: python, matriz

Quiero poder definir una matriz MxN y llenarla con valores de una columna de un data frame, pero lo que pruebo me da error, así que quería saber dónde está mi fallo y si hay alguna opción.
Uno de los códigos que he probado:

```
matA=[]

for i in range(fil):

    matA.append([])

    for j in range(col):

        matA[i].append(df['Quantity'])


matA
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En tu dataframe tienes que utilizar el método `df.iloc` de esa forma puedes acceder a filas y columnas con el número de su índice con el formato `[fila, columna]`

El código utilizando tu fragmento como ejemplo sería:

```
matA=[]

for i in range(fil):
    matA.append([])
    for j in range(col):
        matA[i].append(df.iloc[i,j])


print(matA)
```